# while looping it prints me only 1 value and it's the last one

Tags: php, arrays, web-scraping

I am trying to print my array as a table , but actually it don't really loop inside the array and it print me only the last value

```
<?php
$url='http://myurl.com/';
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
$html = curl_exec($curl);
;
$pro=array();
preg_match_all("/<td>[0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{3})*.[0-9]+DA<\/td>",$html,$match);
$pro['prix']=$match['0'];

preg_match_all('!<td><a href=".*">\K(.+?(?=<\/a><\/td>))!',$html,$match);
$pro['nom']=$match['0'];
$currencies = array_combine($pro['nom'], array_chunk($pro['prix'], 2));

foreach ($currencies as $currency => list($sell, $buy)) {
    $output = ' <td data-th="currency">'.$currency.'</td> <td data-th="sellprice">'.$sell.'</td> <td data-th="buyprice">'.$buy.'</td> '; 
}
curl_close($curl);
?>
<table class="rwd-table">
    <tr>
        <th>Devises</th>
        <th>Achat</th>
        <th>Vente</th>
    </tr>
<?php echo $output ?>
</table>
```

I expected to see all the 11 values , but i only see one and it's the last one 
when i do var_dump it shows well and it print all the array correctly

**The problem was that i forgot $output . = and also to create the empty $output ='' at the begining thanks for the help !
works fine now ! **

Comment: `$output =` make that `$output .=` and then it will concatenate onto that variable instead of overwrite it

Comment: A World of Pain awaits trying to parse HTML with a regex... consider using `DOMDocument / DOMXPath` instead

Answer (score 2):

You need to concatenate your `$output` variable or else it will only show the last one, as the variable gets reassigned each iteration of the loop.

Simply change `$output =` to `$output .=`

**EDIT**: You should instantiate the variable with an empty string before the loop as you cannot concatenate to an undeclared variable and it will throw an error. Add `$output ='';` before the loop starts

Comment: With TYPO's we normally just make a comment and then vote to close the question. A typo is almost never any use to others, and afterall that is the main point of SO, to be a searchable useful resource for deveopler

Answer (score 0):

Your `echo $output;` is at the last when it has only one (last) value.

It should have been inside the loop which passes through all $currencies values using foreach loop.

```
foreach ($currencies as $currency => list($sell, $buy)) {
  $output = ' <td data-th="currency">'.$currency.'</td> <td data- 
  th="sellprice">'.$sell.'</td> <td data-th="buyprice">'.$buy.'</td> '; 
  echo $output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

//  When you are looping in foreach, you are assigning a value to `$output` everytime the loop runs and not realy appending to it. So it's showing the last one from foeach loop : 

foreach ($currencies as $currency => list($sell, $buy)) {

    $output = ' <td data-th="currency">'.$currency.'</td> <td data-th="sellprice">'.$sell.'</td> <td data-th="buyprice">'.$buy.'</td> ';
}

// You can do following : 

$output = '';

foreach ($currencies as $currency => list($sell, $buy)) {

    $output .= ' <td data-th="currency">'.$currency.'</td> <td data-th="sellprice">'.$sell.'</td> <td data-th="buyprice">'.$buy.'</td> ';
}
```

Comment: With TYPO's we normally just make a comment and then vote to close the question. A typo is almost never any use to others, and afterall that is the main point of SO, to be a searchable useful resource for developer

Comment: @RiggsFolly I respectfully disagree and feel explaining how this typo affects the error is equally important. Just highlighting  the typo would not help the person asking question to know why exactly this error occurred.

Comment: And it its a string typo then comment makes sense, This typo is changing the logic altogether. Comment is not enough

Comment: I think my comment covers the issue pretty well actually